# Why doesn't Doctor Strange remove the Infinity Gauntlet from Thanos?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange, avengers-infinity-war

Doctor Strange seemingly has the ability to open portals wherever he wants. We see at the beginning of Infinity War what happens when he closes a portal and someone isn't fully through it.

Is there any reason why he can't open a portal around the left-elbow of Thanos, and then close it?

I realize that Thanos probably wouldn't allow this to happen normally,

> but when he is mostly asleep, and Tony and Spider-Man are pulling on the gauntlet, Doctor Strange has ample opportunity, and plenty of space to just sever Thanos' arm.

Why doesn't he?

Comment: You can't seem to be able to just open up a portal around someone.  It needs to be opened, then have someone go through it, then you can close it whilst they're still transiting, thus severing any body part. For Strange to do this, he would have to had opened the portal with his allies in close proximity.

Comment: @Möoz To be fair, even if that were true, Strange does have the ability to move the portals around through the person. Exhibit A: Dr Strange and Loki's interaction in Thor: Ragnarok.

Comment: So why stop at the arm, why not sever his head?

Comment: This was already asked on Movies and TV. But anyway, are we given any reason to believe that those portals are infinitely “strong,” as it were? That they can be closed around anything, no matter how tough? It’s asking for a lot, even for comic books, to assume that a weapon can damage *anything*.

Comment: @Adamant if it went through the flesh of one of Thanos' "children" why should we not expect it to cut clean through Thanos' flesh? As for the question, I'm personally not a big fan of these questions and think of them as "opinion-based". You watched the same film we did, we have no indication of whether this was possible or why he didn't do it except that the plot required Thanos to win.

Comment: @Edlothiad - ‘Cause minions aren’t as tough as bosses. C’est la vie. Why is it that bullets can hurt Hawkeye, but not Hulk?

Comment: Or to put it another way, do you think that a portal could slice even, say, an *Infinity Stone* in half?

Comment: @Adamant I quite specifically stated "flesh" for that reason. I don't know if a portal could slice an Infinity Stone in half, but that's not what the question is asking. The question is asking why they couldn't just chop off the hand and then remove it from the gauntlet? If it can cut of his "minion"'s (as you put it) hand, I would need evidence against the fact that it wouldn't cut of Thanos'. I don't see the distinction here between Hawkeye and Hulk, Bruce is certainly susceptible to harm in his human state and that's why he's in the Hulk Buster suit.

Comment: @Edlothiad - You don’t see the distinction between Hulk and Hawkeye when it comes to physical injury?

Comment: Wrong word, Freudian slip. I don't see the similarity in the comparison being discussed to the one you made.

Comment: @Edlothiad, Freudian slip?   You have subconscious feelings for Hulk or Hawkeye?  Or both?   So many questions.

Comment: @ThePopMachine for distinctions, not the characters. I was thinking of another discussion about a distinction between two things, and used the word here.

Comment: @Edlothiad:   I was just alluding to the usual connotations of "Freudian slip".

Comment: @Mooz - Just wanted to point out that DR. Strange can manipulate the position of an opened portal as he did in Thor: Ragnarok

Comment: Because part 2 needs to happen

Comment: the writers decided to close off all plot questions by having strange look into the future

Comment: The chaps at "HISHE" ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcEbZ_vexA8&t=542s ) already approached this same concept from a different angle.  Instead of Thor throwing Stormbreaker for chest (or head) shot, he used the axe blade to sever Thanos' arm off at the shoulder.  Dr. Strange might have had mystic insights to guide his actions, but Thor shouldn't have tried for the kill shot and been more strategic.

Comment: This guy should watch the infinity war Hishe. Or the endgame one.

Comment: @Möoz side-effects of beheading Thanos may include weight gain, depression, compulsive gaming, relinquishing your throne to a Valkyrie, and tiny beard plaits.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Don't forget, 'Picking fights with young people on line'

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### Not everything or everyone is equally tough

Fenrir’s teeth can penetrate Hulk’s skin (and that’s cinematically treated as pretty surprising), but when Bruce Banner tries to shoot himself in the mouth with a bullet, it will just bounce off the Hulk’s digestive tract.

> BRUCE: I got low. I didn’t see an end, so I
>              put a bullet in my mouth and the other
>              guy spit it out!
>
> <sub>*The Avengers*</sub>

I think this demonstrates fairly well that “flesh” is not just one thing in the MCU. Some creatures are far, far more durable than others, and Thanos is probably near the top of that list. The flesh of a mutated berserker or an alien god are very different from the body of a regular human being.

**Just because some of Thanos’s minions are fragile enough that a portal can fairly easily sever their limbs, doesn’t mean that *Thanos* himself is.**

This is a common fantasy theme, particularly in comic books. On *Supergirl*, for instance, regular bullets might just bounce off of her,  but an [energy axe](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Vartox%27s_axe) is a different matter.

Are we to assume that a sling-ring portal can sever anything, no matter its durability? Hulk, Thanos, even the Infinity Stones themselves? The implicit assumption in the question is that the sling portals simply “cut through” anything, that there’s no force involved in their closing, but we don’t have anything to suggest that this is the case, and a lot to suggest it’s probably not.

### The Power Stone might have increased his durability even further

Recall that in *Guardians of the Galaxy*, the Power Stone greatly increased Ronan’s durability. To quote the [Wiki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Stone):

> Similarly to Malekith while he was wielding the Aether, Ronan’s
>   durability was enhanced while bearing his Power Stone-infused
>   Cosmi-Rod. He withstood a direct, close range shot from the Hadron
>   Enforcer, with no apparent injury as well as not being at all affected
>   by the crashing of the Dark Aster as he walked away from the massive
>   wreckage of his ship as if he had landed without problems.

The Power Stone was the *first* stone that Thanos acquired. Whatever his ordinary strength and durability, it would have been increased beyond all reason. And, as noted in the description, the other stones may have increased Thanos’s resistance to damage as well.

### Strange had tried other things

As noted in the [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/186728/51379), the Time Stone has allowed Doctor Strange to see all the possible outcomes. All we can say is that *something* would have gone wrong if they’d tried that. Perhaps, indeed, the thing that would have gone wrong would be that the portal wouldn’t be able to sever Thanos’s skin before he could react, but perhaps any number of other things would have gone wrong.

Comment: "whatever happened, happened, and couldn't have happened any other way" - Morpheus

Comment: As evidence of Thanos' durability, they fight him for several minutes and the best they collectively manage is a tiny scratch on his cheek.

Comment: What's the "a lot" of evidence to support that sling portals can't cut through anything?

Comment: @theonlygusti - Hi. Sorry, edits aren’t meant to be used to reply to the author of a post. Your comment does that well enough. :)

Comment: @Adamant yeah but an edit almost completely ensures you see and engage with it

Comment: The portal doesn't need to "cut" anything though. If you open a portal to, say, Alaska, and put Thanos' hand through it, then his hand is in Alaska and the body is on Titan. When you close the portal nothing really changes, his hand is still in Alaska and his body is still on Titan. Durability has nothing to do with it, as soon as the hand goes through the portal it is already severed, it just doesn't it yet.

Comment: @Maxim - Your assumption is that you can *close the portal*.

Comment: (Well, there's also an assumption about the range of portals).

Comment: @theonlygusti - Yes, I engaged with it, and rejected your edit. Please don't misuse edits; it makes more work for people.

Comment: @Adamant Well, portals aren't a thing that exists, but it seems from an intuitive logic you'd need a lot of energy to keep a portal open, so to close it, you just stop supplying it with energy, and it'll disappear.

Comment: @Maxim - From an "intuitive" logic, when it takes energy to keep something open, and one let's go, closes until it hits an obstacle it can't go through. Since this intuition leads to sensible results consistent with the film, and the other leads to some curious implications, I think we can trust the former more.

Comment: @Adamant Yeah, I would imagine the portal would just disappear, since portals can already move matter rather arbitrarily, it seems weird to me to think of them encountering physical obstacles as they seem "above" physical space, but unless we have real portals any interpretation of them is reasonable as long as it's internally consistent within the story, but I do wish they'd at least try that, and/or have pre-established a rule that portals can't always close easily (unless they did in Dr. Strange and I forgot, which is possible).

Comment: @Maxim As of Spiderman: No Way Home, we now know it is not that simple to close a sling ring portal.

Answer (score 39):

Because Strange has seen over 14 million combinations and variations of the future and they lose in every one of them but 1. It is the writers way to say: I know what you're thinking, but it has to be like this. Because we, the Fate, say so.

Presumably, he had tried that exact thing in at least one of the variations and it had failed.

Answer (score 17):

Joe Russo answered this question in an [interview about Endgame](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/bj0it4/joe_russos_qa_about_the_plot_of_avengers_endgame/?utm_content=body&utm_medium=post_embed&utm_name=97023cf983234c88b025f7fd4b98fc0a&utm_source=embedly&utm_term=bj0it4):

> **Q.** ***In both Infinity War and End Game, the heroes tried their best to take the glove away from Thanos, so why didn't Doctor Strange just cut off Thanos' hand with his ability?***
>
> **A.** Thanos' skin is almost impenetrable, we don't know whether Doctor Strange had the capability to do it. If he failed to cut it on time, Thanos would still able to do the snap. Doctor Strange realized this issue during his millions of test runs.

Comment: Upvooooooote. This is exactly what I said, and it seems it's exactly what the writers were thinking.