# Why didn't the Avengers just cut off the hand of Thanos instead of trying to take the Infinity Gauntlet off?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

I guess they should have just cut off the hand of Thanos at that time. But why didn't they do that? Is it not possible to cut his hand?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! This is a nice first question but it appears to have been asked before. However, the short answer is simply as Dr. Strange says himself "This was the only way". Lastly, don't forget to take the [tour]!

Comment: ohh Thank you very much. I will not forget to take the tour :-D :-)

Comment: One does not simply cut off the hand of Thanos.

Comment: Yes, could've use the portal trick (1. put hand through portal, 2. Close portal, 3. ????, 4. Profit)

Answer (score 6):

### They didn't have the power to do so

This seems as a generalization of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186722/why-doesnt-doctor-strange-remove-the-infinity-gauntlet-from-thanos), where the OP tries to identify  why Dr. Strange didn't use the same technique as in the beginning of the movie,

> to chop Thanos's hand.

Well, apart from Dr. Strange, the only other character at that time who was supposed to be able to do that was Iron Man, but

> Thanos seems to be immune to Iron Man energy blasts -apart from falling to the ground.

All the other characters at that time

> meaning Star Lord, Drax, Nebula and Spider-Man

do not have a special ability or weapon to carry out such a task.

Comment: thank you very much. That clears my doubts..now I can rest in peace :-) :-)

Comment: @sathsara: “now I can rest in peace” — good lord, don’t kill yourself! Or at least wait until you’ve seen the sequel?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite :-D :-D yahh I think death can wait :-P